# Solve no final variable inside Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there is a way to convert the following code to Java 8 Stream.

```
    final List ret = new ArrayList(values.size());
    double tmp = startPrice;
    for (final Iterator it = values.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      final DiscountValue discountValue = ((DiscountValue) it.next()).apply(quantity, tmp, digits, currencyIsoCode);
      tmp -= discountValue.getAppliedValue();
      ret.add(discountValue);
    }
```

Java 8 streams complains about no final variable tmp ? Is there a way to solve such situations ?

Local variable tmp defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

[image]

Comment: Step 1: Use generics, not *raw* `Iterator`. Why is `values` a raw `Collection`, and not a generic `Collection<DiscountValue>`?

Comment: An enhanced for loop would make more sense here.

Comment: Actually this is very old code. I am refactoring the whole package written 10 years ago using latest java version. thanks for the suggestion , Will do that surely.

Comment: I don’t see any Stream code that could complain about no final variable tmp…

Comment: @Holger : updated. I know it's the same old story.  "Show what have you tried stuff". :)))

Comment: why does the apply method need the tmp variable?

Comment: @Cyril Don't go in the naming convention. Consider instead it's essential variable. As i said it was written 10 years ago by somebody else. If i see apply method "temp" is essential there :)

Comment: Well if you want to convert it to java 8 streams, you should remove the mutation from the loop and use map and/or reduce. Converting it 1:1 to java 8 forEach is kinda pointless. If you don't want to change the logic, you should just convert it to generics + normal foreach loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, change the code to use generics and an enhanced `for` loop. Assuming `values` is then a `List<DiscountValue>`, this is what you get:

```
List<DiscountValue> ret = new ArrayList<>(values.size());
double tmp = startPrice;
for (DiscountValue value : values) {
    DiscountValue discountValue = value.apply(quantity, tmp, digits, currencyIsoCode);
    tmp -= discountValue.getAppliedValue();
    ret.add(discountValue);
}
```

I'd suggest staying with that, and not convert it to streams, but if you insist, you can use a one-element array as a value-holder.

Note that `ret` and `tmp` doesn't have to be declared `final`, as long as they are effectively-final.

```
List<DiscountValue> ret = new ArrayList<>(values.size());
double[] tmp = { startPrice };
values.stream().forEachOrdered(v -> {
    DiscountValue discountValue = v.apply(quantity, tmp[0], digits, currencyIsoCode);
    tmp[0] -= discountValue.getAppliedValue();
    ret.add(discountValue);
});
```

As you can see, you haven't gained anything by using streams. The code is actually *worse*, so ... *don't*.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AtomicReference variable.

```
AtomicReference<Double> temp = new AtomicReference<>();
temp.set(356.65);

Double[] values = {23.4, 45.6,9.4,1.43};

Stream.of(values).forEach(val -> {
          temp.set(temp.get() - val);
});

System.out.println(temp.get());
```

Output

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe...
276.82

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: this is a safer way to do it compared to just a holder in the accepted answer, but it can still be prone to errors and unexpected behaviour if the variable is altered in other places